# Can't get a SVG circle animated

Tags: css, animation, svg, fade

I got a map with 12 dots that each need to fade in on hover like in the demo. The problem is that I can't get the radius animated. Is it possible to fade the radius size of the SVG in with CSS or is there another way to do it? My second problem is that I can't get a background image in my SVG's. Is there a solution?

[My code...](http://jsbin.com/wavibaka/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: You might want to think about abstracting the circle into a `def` and just re-using it instead of defining it each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ya it is possible..

## [Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/wavibaka/8/edit)

css

```
#container {
}

#kaart {
}

.fullkaart {
    fill:#7FC577;
}

.cirkel {
fill: green;
-webkit-transform: scale(1);
-moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
     -o-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
-webkit-transform-origin: center;
   -moz-transform-origin: center;
    -ms-transform-origin: center;
     -o-transform-origin: center;
        transform-origin: center;
    -webkit-transition: fill, -webkit-transform
   -moz-transition: fill, -webkit-transform
    -ms-transition: fill, -webkit-transform
     -o-transition: fill, -webkit-transform
        transition: fill, -webkit-transform
  -webkit-transition-duration: 3s;
   -moz-transition-duration: 3s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 3s;
     -o-transition-duration: 3s;
        transition-duration: 3s;
     }

     .cirkel:hover{
       fill: yellow;
       -webkit-transform: scale(2);
   -moz-transform: scale(2);
    -ms-transform: scale(2);
     -o-transform: scale(2);
        transform: scale(2);
      -webkit-transition: fill, -webkit-transform
   -moz-transition: fill, -webkit-transform
    -ms-transition: fill, -webkit-transform
     -o-transition: fill, -webkit-transform
        transition: fill, -webkit-transform
      -moz-transition-duration: 3s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 3s;
     -o-transition-duration: 3s;
        transition-duration: 3s;
```

HTML

```
<circle class="cirkel" cx="245.929" cy="68.256" r="5.08" onmouseover="evt.target.setAttribute('r', '10');" onmouseout="evt.target.setAttribute('r', '5.08');"/>
```

I removed the onmouseover and onmouseout attributes from first two circle tags.
remove them and adjust scale accordingly

Comment: Does not work (Chrome v37). It enlarges the circle then removes it completely.

Comment: @DaanTimmer you want to fadein the circle? as in opacity 0 -> 1? what did you mean by fade the radius size?

Comment: When I look at OP's code, the inner white circle gets bigger while the outer circle has the same offset from the inner circle all the time. Also, the inner circle changes from white to orange-like. Where as in your version, the inner circle stays white (does get bigger) and once it has reached full size disappears. (I am not the OP btw)

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly where I was looking for :)